# ios Firebase Push Notification project

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, push

I'm very new at Firebase and i'm looking for an iOS project with push notifications implemented, to look how Firebase push notifications work and learn of it. 
Can someone tell me where i can find it?

Thank you!

Comment: they have their samples. check the docs site. this is not a place to ask for reference projects/libs.

Comment: For a codelab that walks you though building an iOS app: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED: SWIFT 3.0:**

**How to integrate your iOS project with Firebase.**

In Order to integrate your project with Firebase for push notifications you need to do the following:

1. Integrate your project with Firebase by using CocoaPods. Open **Terminal** and write **cd** and then drag the folder that contains your project to the Terminal so you avoid writing the whole path.
2. Once you're inside the folder in Terminal, write:

   **$ pod init**

and new file will be created for you inside the project called **Podfile**

3. Open **Podfile** file in your text editor and add **pod 'Firebase'** before the **end** keyword.
4. Save the file and go back to Terminal and make sure you are still inside the project path.
5. Then write **pod install** in Terminal and this should start downloading Firebase and integrating it with your project.

6.Once done downloading you should see a new file in your project folder with **.xcworkspace** extension. This is the file you should open from now on.

7. go to the link below and generate your certificate in order for you to upload it to your Firebase project in the console.

https://www.mobiloud.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-export-push-notification-certificate-p12/

8. Open your project and navigate to AppDelegate and do the following;

   // Import framework

   ```
     import Firebase
   ```

on the top of your App.

9. Now inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method add

   // Use Firebase library to configure APIs

   ```
   FIRApp.configure()
   ```
10. Inside registerForRemoteNotifications method add the following:

    ```
     let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    ```

**UPDATED: SWIFT 3.0:**

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.badge,.sound]) { (granted:Bool, error:Error?) in

            if granted {

            }else{

            }

        }


        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate  = self
```

and for the delegate:

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

}

 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}
```

11. You should add the following method to your AppDelegate in order for you to receive messages while the app is running;

    ```
    func application(application:UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

     print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

     }
    ```
12. Follow the link below to test sending a push

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device

Answer (score -1):

There is a thing provided by any SDK, which is called **Documentation**. And here is the link to Firebase [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup). Follow this step by step its well explained.

Also you can find the example project for FCM(cloud messaging) from this GitHub's [repository](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios) under messaging.

During this journey if you got stuck anywhere, then post your real question(problem) here, someone can guide you through.